# Julia - plot with 2 arrays of same size

Tags: plot, julia

I have two arrays:

```
sigma = logspace(-4,4,5)
```

which looks like `= [10^-4,10^-2,10,10^2,10^4]`

and some other array that contains 5 values which were generated from norm-2 of some 5 different vectors.
assume this is the second array:

```
Xnorm = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I'm trying to plot those two arrays:

```
figure()
plot(Xnorm,sigma)
```

I would like that sigma will represent the X-axis and Xnorm the y-axis.
The result right now is an empty graph. (I've tried to swap between both of them also).

Unfortunately, I did not found any good documentation for plotting with array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the plotting library

```
sigma = logspace(-4,4,5)
Xnorm = [1,2,3,4,5]
# Pkg.add("Plots") # Do this only the first time to install.
using Plots
plot(Xnorm,sigma)
```

Comment: Thanks,
I've been using "PyPlot" don't really know why it was not enough.